# How can even there be a non-zero BMS vector field with zero asymptotic data?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, vector-fields

Following the BMS approach, one spacetime $(M,g)$ is asymptotically flat when:

1. We can find a *Bondi gauge* set of coordinates $(u,r,x^A)$ characterized by $$g_{rr}=g_{rA}=0,\quad \partial_r\det\left(\dfrac{g_{AB}}{r^2}\right)=0\tag{1}.$$
2. The range of the $r$ coordinate is $r_0\leq r < +\infty$ and the $x^A$ coordinates parameterize a two-sphere $S^2$
3. The metric has asymptotic behavior (where $\gamma_{AB}$ is the $S^2$ round metric) $$g_{uu}=-1+O(r^{-1}),\quad g_{ur}=-1+O(r^{-2})\quad g_{uA}=O(1),\\\quad g_{AB}=r^2\gamma_{AB}+O(1)\tag{2}.$$

In that scenario a BMS vector field is a vector field in $(M,g)$ which preserves (1) and (2) when we vary the metric as $\delta g = L_X g$. The space of all such vectors is then the $\mathfrak{bms}_4$ algebra.

It is possible to show that such a vector field is identified by a pair $(f,Y)$ where $f\in L^2(S^2)$ and $Y$ is a Conformal Killing Vector on $S^2$ such that its leading behavior is: \begin{align}    X &= \left(\frac{u}{2}D_A Y^A + f\right)\partial_u + \left(-\frac{r}{2}D_A Y^A -\frac{u}{2} D_A Y^A +\frac{1}{2}D_A D^A f + O(r^{-1})\right)\partial_r\\ & + \left(Y^A -\frac{D^A f + \frac{u}{2}D^A (D_B Y^B)}{r}+O(r^{-2})\right)\partial_A.\tag{3}\end{align}

Moreover preservation of (1) still demands two conditions. Preservation of $g_{rA}=0$ demands: $$\partial_r X^A = -g_{ur}g^{AB}\partial_B X^u \tag{4}$$

and preservation of the determinant condition demands $g^{AB}L_X g_{AB} =0$ which becomes:

$$X^r g^{AB}\partial_r g_{AB}=-\bigg(X^u g^{AB}\partial_u g_{AB}+X^C g^{AB}\partial_C g_{AB}+2 g^{AB}\partial_A X^u g_{uB}+2g^{AB}\partial_A X^C g_{CB}\bigg)\tag{5}$$

which in effect fully determines $X^r$.

Now in ["Advanced Lectures on General Relativity"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07064) the author says that *"Trivial boundary diffeomorphisms $f=Y^A=0$ form an ideal this algebra"*.

But why isn't the set $f = Y^A=0$ comprised of just the zero vector? I mean if $f = Y^A = 0$ then $X^u =0$. If $X^u = 0$ then (4) implies that $X^A = Y^A$ and therefore $X^A =0$. Finally using $X^u,X^A = 0$ in (5) implies that, since $g^{AB}\partial_r g_{AB}\neq 0$, we have $X^r = 0$.

What am I missing here? What is my misunderstanding? How can there be BMS vector fields, preserving (1) and (2), with $f = Y^A =0$ which are not identically zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

> It is possible to show that such a vector field is identified by a pair $(f,Y)$ where …

vector field $X$ is *not uniquely* identified by this pair $(f,Y)$, only its action on the boundary data, while the vector field itself is defined not only near the boundary but everywhere “inside” the manifold. In other words, this pair $(f,Y)$ says nothing about behavior of $X$ at finite values of radial coordinate, only about its asymptotic behavior.

For example we can choose $X$ to be arbitrary for $r<r_1$ (for some $r_1<\infty$) and identically zero for $r_2 < r <\infty$ (with $r_2>r_1$), while for $r_1<r<r_2$ we can choose $X$ interpolating between two behaviors to satisfy the necessary smoothness conditions.

It is easy to see that for such example vector field the pair $(f,Y)$ would be zero. Thus this $X$ is a nontrivial example of the generator of a trivial boundary diffeomorphism. As an aside, such construction is related to so called Einstein's [hole argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_argument).

Also note, that fields $X$  corresponding to trivial boundary diffeomorphisms do not have to be identically zero in some vicinity of the boundary, they just have to approach zero fast enough to not alter the boundary data.

Comment: Hi @A.V.S, thanks ! I was suspecting my conclusion to be wrong but where my argument breaks down? I mean, $X$ should preserve (1). This demands $L_X g_{ur}=0$ which gives $\partial_r X^u =0$. Therefore $X^u$ is *exactly* given by (3). Now imposing $L_X g_{rA}=0$ yields (4) which for $X^u =0$ implies that $X^A = Y^A$ and again supposing $(f,Y)=0$ gives $X^A =0$. Finally preserving the third equation in (1) gives (5) and the RHS vanishes therefore we have $X^r =0$. Something is *clearly wrong* in this argument but I still didn't spot it.

Comment: *where my argument breaks down?* It breaks because (3) is only an expansion of $X$ on the boundary. Penrose et al. treatment gives $\scr I^{+}$ manifold structure, but it is a manifold of codimension 1. Behavior of $X$ on it says *nothing* about values of $X$ outside immediate vicinity of $\scr I^{+}$. Note that “Bondi gauge” is in fact a boundary condition imposing constraints only in the vicinity of null infinity. It leaves a lot of gauge freedom in the bulk …

Comment: … We could contrast this with Lorenz gauge of flat space EM theory. It has residual gauge freedom with the generator satisfying $\Box f = 0$. So specifying $f$ on the boundary uniquely fixes $f$ in the bulk. But for Bondi gauge $X$ does not have to satisfy any equations in the bulk. It could by anything!

Comment: But in Compère's notes mentioned in the OP the author says that one should demand $X$ to preserve "Bondi gauge" exactly (pages 75, 76), not just for large $r$ up to corrections of specified order. Preserving (1) gives three equations $L_X g_{rr}=0$, $L_X g_{rA}=0$ and $g^{AB}L_X g_{AB}=0$. The first is $\partial_r X^u =0$ and the others are (4) and (5) in the OP. These are equations for $X$ in the bulk as long as one stays in the domain of the $(u,r,x^A)$ chart. Is your point that the domain of this chart may not cover the whole manifold, being defined only near $\mathscr{I}^+$?

Comment: My point was that “Bondi gauge” may be meaningful only for $r_0\le r<\infty$ (as per your own Q. list item 2 or some more general *vicinity of null infinity*). For smaller values of radial coordinate we may have wormholes, time machines, warp drives, 3-branes or maybe just black holes forming, merging and evaporating. All of those things could potentially make imposing BG for the whole manifold impossible, yet it would still be asymptotically flat spacetime. So “the bulk” where we can make $X$ anything we want is $r<r_0$ plus (possibly) regions not even covered by $(r,u,x^A)$ coordinates.

Comment: Oh I see, the point is that we are only being able to constrain $X$ in the open subset on which the coordinates $(u,r,x^A)$ are defined, which can be just a small neighborhood of $\mathscr{I}^+$. So for instance in the maximally extended Schwarzschild geometry, in the asymptotically flat exterior region $r > 2M$ we could use the outgoing Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates to implement BG. In *that region* we can constrain $X$ in terms of $(f,Y)$ but in the rest of the manifold we can make it whatever we want. Did I get it ? Thanks a lot for the help again !

Comment: Yes! And remember, when the other end of the interval is infinity, “small neighborhood” is relative. We could define diffeomorphisms that would mangle Schw. geometry up to $r=10^{20} M$ and it would still be *trivial on the boundary* since we can always set $r_0 = 2\cdot  10^{20} M$.